# Selenium4 tests fail with timeout on chrome 106

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4229&sort=-id

Selenium4 tests fail with timeout on chrome 106. Works fine on 105. There is no change in locators/selectors in our application. Tests are failing on local Mac book runs too. Anyone else see this issue? Appreciate any help on this, thanks

```
org.junit.runners.model.TestTimedOutException: test timed out after 10 minutes
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Signaller.block(CompletableFuture.java:1709)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3323)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1788)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1928)
at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:206)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:66)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler$$Lambda$118/1813158748.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent$$Lambda$326/1540383715.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$$Lambda$119/204587817.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:51)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent$$Lambda$326/1540383715.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$$Lambda$119/204587817.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:124)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.TracedHttpClient.execute(TracedHttpClient.java:55)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor.execute(TracedCommandExecutor.java:51)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:567)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:622)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:626)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getCurrentUrl(RemoteWebDriver.java:342)
at com.saasure.test.junit.rules.ScreenShotCaptureRule.captureScreenShot(ScreenShotCaptureRule.java:101)
at com.saasure.test.junit.rules.ScreenShotCaptureRule.captureScreenShot(ScreenShotCaptureRule.java:71)
at com.saasure.test.junit.rules.ScreenShotCaptureRule.failed(ScreenShotCaptureRule.java:49)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher.failedQuietly(TestWatcher.java:84)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher.access$300(TestWatcher.java:46)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:62)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:298)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout$CallableStatement.call(FailOnTimeout.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: Did you check if there's any update in the chrome driver available?

Comment: @LibinThomas we do have the latest or the updated version of the chromedriver for 106

Comment: looks like other folks are also seeing this issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=4229&sort=-id